# Tomcat8 crash under load - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, StandardWrapperValve

Tags: tomcat, indexoutofboundsexception, tomcat8

My Tomcat8 (CentOS) webserver is expiring a high load today, > 100,000 requests per hour.

At one point the server crashed/hung. I rebooted the server, and it seem fine and has not crashed again so far.

The only thing I can find as to why it crashed is this error logged to the lochost-20016-10-10.log file at the same time as the crash.

I'm not certain if it is the cause, or just an affect, but I have not seen the error previously.

If anyone has seen this error and knows the cause, please share your information.

```
10-Oct-2016 12:25:27.370 SEVERE [http-nio-80-exec-86] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [] threw exception
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:322)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:418)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:406)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.copyRange(DefaultServlet.java:2210)
        at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.copy(DefaultServlet.java:2044)
        at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource(DefaultServlet.java:1008)
        at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:398)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:436)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:177)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: or perhaps, is there a way to limit the load on the server? i.e. what happens when it gets too many requests, other than crashing...

Comment: perhaps this link might help a bit https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6014440 ,depends on what you are trying to achieve though.

Comment: It seems to be a bug from tomcat as I could find many forum threads for java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Maybe you can try to find the issue through the server logs just before crashing. That just check the appication code that executed just before crashing the server.